# Sharepoint Filter

Tags: sharepoint, listview, view, task

I have two lists,

Status

1. Name (string)
2. Active (yes/no)

Task

1. Name (string)
2. Status (Lookup to Status list)

I have the following statuses (These can be changed at any time by the client):

- New, Active = Yes
- Open, Active = Yes
- Not Resolved, Active = No
- Resolved, Active = No

I want to create a view for the Tasks list, that shows all active tasks... How would I go about this?

Thanks!
Albert

Comment: Projects list? Do you have a typo somewhere? I don't see anything about a Projects list...

Comment: sorry, tasks list, corrected above

Answer (score 0):

Could you do something with a calculated field (build an if statement) and then filter your view on this?

Answer (score 0):

Take a glance at [SharePoint Lists Conditional Formatting using SharePoint Designer 2010](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/balsharfi/archive/2011/10/20/sharepoint-lists-conditional-formatting-using-sharepoint-designer-2010.aspx)
**OR** 
Simply, choose "Modify view" and set the condition in filter option like the following image:
[Filter option](http://www.mssharepointtips.com/tipimages/1008_5.JPG)